# How do I append '-f' flag to each items in a file and save to variable?

Tags: unix, sed, ksh

in ksh, I am trying to add some option flag (-f) to each item which I read from a file
For ex.

```
ls > fileList.txt

// fileList.txt contains
// test1.out
// test2.out
// test3.out

// I tried this but I get this error 
// error :  -f: not found [No such file or directory]
files=`cat fileList.txt | sed 's/^/-f /'`

// What I want to see is $files show
// -f test1.out -f test2.out -f test3.out
// so I can call another script with this new argument
processFile $files
```

How can I do this??

Comment: You don't really have `//` at the front of your data lines? Assuming you don't then `files=$( sed 's/^/-f /' < fileList.txt); echo $files` worked for me in `ksh`. If that doesn't work, did you create `fileList.txt` in MSWindows (or use ftp etc)? If so, then clean up file with `dos2unix fileList.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: I am still getting same error..
 -f: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: as the result of `echo $files`? You have to take this apart piece by piece to figure out where it's not working as you expect. Are you redirecting std-err to `/dev/null` so you can't see any error messages. Do you need to use `files=$(sed 's/^/-f /' < /full/path/to/fileList.txt)` ? Learn to debug by taking code apart to the smallest chunk to be sure it is working. What happens with just `sed 's/^/-f /' /full/path/to/fileList.txt` (for instance). If that works, Add the next layer. Copy/paste to cmd-lines. Does it work there but not in the script? Update your Q with best info. Good luck.

Comment: Use `--` for ending the list op options of printf.
`printf -- "-f %s " $(ls)` is wrong when your files have spaces or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop in each file with a variable as below to get desired output:

```
for i in `cat fileList.txt`
do
        echo -n " -f $i"
done
echo
```